# Origin of the factor of $i$ in the photon propagator

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, conventions, complex-numbers, greens-functions, propagator

I'm following Peskin and Schroeder and am having trouble tracking down a particular factor of i that is persistently used in the definition of Green's functions. For example, equation 9.52 states that

$$(-k^2g_\mu\nu+k_\mu k_\nu)\tilde{D}_F^{\nu\rho}(k)=i \delta_\mu^\rho.\tag{9.52}$$

If $\tilde{D}_F$ is the Green's function for this system, why is there a factor of $i$ on the RHS instead of just the delta?

Comment: This is the imaginary unit. It is just a number factor included in teh definition of teh Green"s function, like one could have included $-1$, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help Vadim. This just seems arbitrary to me. What's to stop you from defining a Green's function as 3 times a delta function?

Comment: Typically this factor will cancel out when performing Feynmann-Dyson expansion, because there is another $i$ in the evolution operator in interaction representation, so it may present some conveniences. But it is essentially a matter of convention.